# Enumerating tabs in IE8 and Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, tabs, vb.net

Is there a way to list the text that appears in each of the tabs of IE8 and Firefox as part of the list of running processes along with the handle.

I can list all the running processes fine with their hwnd's but I cant list all of the tabs that are open in either IE8 or Firefox, only the active tab.

Preferably in VB10 Visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

For IE, first add a COM reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls`, then use the following code:

```
For Each j As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In New SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass()
    If j.Name = "Windows Internet Explorer" Then
        ListView1.Items.Add(j.LocationName) 'j.HWND will return the handle
    End If
Next
```